# Select option to filter results clear

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table php mysql with a script for brand, model, year and doors... When You select Brand, gives model based on brand...
I have two main problems. After select the model, if i change the brand, i have 0 results, need to select the model for respective brand. I want, when select brand always, reset the table.

Other problem, is, when no brand selected, in the options i can find all models from database. I want to only see models after pick some brand.

```
    <script>
    function getUniqueValuesFromColumn() {
        
    var unique_col_values_dict = {}
    allFilters = document.querySelectorAll(".table-filter")
    allFilters.forEach((filter_i) => {
        col_index = filter_i.parentElement.getAttribute("col-index");
        // alert(col_index)
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#emp-table > tbody > tr")
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            cell_value = row.querySelector("td:nth-child("+col_index+")").innerHTML;
            // if the col index is already present in the dict
            if (col_index in unique_col_values_dict) {
                // if the cell value is already present in the array
                if (unique_col_values_dict[col_index].includes(cell_value)) {
                    // alert(cell_value + " is already present in the array : " + unique_col_values_dict[col_index])
                } else {
                    unique_col_values_dict[col_index].push(cell_value)
                    // alert("Array after adding the cell value : " + unique_col_values_dict[col_index])
            }


            } else {
                unique_col_values_dict[col_index] = new Array(cell_value)
            }
        });

        
    });

    updateSelectOptions(unique_col_values_dict)
    };

    // Add <option> tags to the desired columns based on the unique values
    function updateSelectOptions(unique_col_values_dict) {
    allFilters = document.querySelectorAll(".table-filter")

    allFilters.forEach((filter_i) => {
        col_index = filter_i.parentElement.getAttribute('col-index')

        unique_col_values_dict[col_index].forEach((i) => {
            filter_i.innerHTML = filter_i.innerHTML + `\n<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`
        });

    });
    };
    // Create filter_rows() function
    // filter_value_dict {2 : Value selected, 4:value, 5: value}
    function filter_rows() {
    allFilters = document.querySelectorAll(".table-filter")
    var filter_value_dict = {}
    allFilters.forEach((filter_i) => {
        col_index = filter_i.parentElement.getAttribute('col-index')
        value = filter_i.value
        if (value != "all") {
            filter_value_dict[col_index] = value;
        }
    });

    var col_cell_value_dict = {};
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#emp-table tbody tr");
    rows.forEach((row) => {
        var display_row = true;
        allFilters.forEach((filter_i) => {
            col_index = filter_i.parentElement.getAttribute('col-index')
            col_cell_value_dict[col_index] = row.querySelector("td:nth-child(" + col_index+ ")").innerHTML
        })
        for (var col_i in filter_value_dict) {
            filter_value = filter_value_dict[col_i]
            row_cell_value = col_cell_value_dict[col_i]
            
            if (row_cell_value.indexOf(filter_value) == -1 && filter_value != "all") {
                display_row = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (display_row == true) {
            row.style.display = "table-row"
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none"
        }
    })    


    }

    function resetTable() {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#emp-table tbody tr");
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    row.style.display = "table-row";
  });
  allFilters = document.querySelectorAll(".table-filter");
  allFilters.forEach((filter_i) => {
    filter_i.value = "all";
  });
  getUniqueValuesFromColumn();
}  
</script>


    <div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table id="emp-table">

   


        <thead>
        <th col-index="1">Marca
    <select id="marca-select" class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows()">
        <option value="all"></option>
      
    </select>
</th>
<th col-index="2">Modelo
    <select id="modelo-select" class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows()">
        <option value="all"></option>

    </select>      

</th>


<th col-index="3">Ano
    <select id="ano-select" class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows()">
        <option value="all"></option>
       
    </select>
</th>

<th col-index="4">Portas
    <select id="portas-select" class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows()">
        <option value="all"></option>
      
    </select>
</th>
 
            <th col-index = 5>Link...
                
            </th>
          <th>
  
</th>  


        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
try {


    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT marca, modelo, ano, portas, link FROM chuventos";

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['marca'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['modelo'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['ano'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['portas'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['link'] ?></td>
         
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
            
          
        </tbody>
<tfoot> <tr> </td>        <button onclick="resetTable()">Reset Table</button></td></tr>
        </tfoot>

        <script>

            
    // Add event listener to the Marca select element
    document.getElementById("marca-select").addEventListener("change", function() {
        var modeloSelect = document.getElementById("modelo-select");
                modeloSelect.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
        var marca = this.value;
        // Create AJAX request to fetch the data from the server-side script
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "fetch_models.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
               
                // Update the options in the Modelo select element
                var options = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var select = document.getElementById("modelo-select");
                select.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    select.innerHTML += "<option value='" + options[i] + "'>" + options[i] + "</option>";
                }
                // Clear the options in the Ano select element
                var anoSelect = document.getElementById("ano-select");
                anoSelect.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
                var portasSelect = document.getElementById("portas-select");
                portasSelect.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
            }
        };
        xhr.send("marca=" + encodeURIComponent(marca));
    });
// Add event listener to the Modelo select element
document.getElementById("modelo-select").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var modelo = this.value;
    
    // Clear the options in the Ano select element
    var anoSelect = document.getElementById("ano-select");
    anoSelect.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
    
    // Clear the options in the Portas select element
    var portasSelect = document.getElementById("portas-select");
    portasSelect.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
    
    // Create AJAX request to fetch the data from the server-side script
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "fetch_years.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // Update the options in the Ano select element
            var options = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                anoSelect.innerHTML += "<option value='" + options[i] + "'>" + options[i] + "</option>";
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send("marca=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("marca-select").value) + "&modelo=" + encodeURIComponent(modelo));
});


// Add event listener to the Ano select element
document.getElementById("ano-select").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var ano = this.value;
    var modelo = document.getElementById("modelo-select").value;
    var marca = document.getElementById("marca-select").value;
    // Create AJAX request to fetch the data from the server-side script
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "fetch_portas.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // Update the options in the Portas select element
            var options = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var select = document.getElementById("portas-select");
            select.innerHTML = "<option value='all'></option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                select.innerHTML += "<option value='" + options[i] + "'>" + options[i] + "</option>";
            }
            
        }
    };
    xhr.send("marca=" + encodeURIComponent(marca) + "&modelo=" + encodeURIComponent(modelo) + "&ano=" + encodeURIComponent(ano));
});
</script>



    </table>
    <!-- <script>getUniqueValuesFromColumn()
    </script> -->
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            console.log(document.querySelector("#emp-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) ").innerHTML);
        };

        getUniqueValuesFromColumn()
        
    </script>
```